# Creating a runnable jar from eclipse

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have been trying this for past 2 days and I can't get anywhere. I am using Eclipse and I have 4 `src` files and few external library files that I am using. Now that I am finished with my application, I am trying to create a runnable jar from Eclipse. When I do it from my home pc, it works fine, but when I copy and paste that jar file into my work PC, it doesn't load at all. Also, from my work PC when I try to create the jar file only the `JFrame` and all the GUI interface loads up, the other options within the interface don't seem to work.

I want to be able to create a .jar or some kind of executable file that anyone who I gave that ONE file to can use without having any JRE, JDK and etc. I thought having Java installed in a computer would work, would they need all of these kits? I want it to make it work without using the source files and libraries through a `cmd` or IDE.

Edit:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar filename.jar
```

works on command line. but it gives me heap space error if I do

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

Exact erorr:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EVENTQUEUE-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is VM argument possible through eclipse when creating the jar? I don't want to create an `exe` to put the argument.

Comment: "Having Java installed" means having either the JRE or the JDK.  For end-users (not developers) that usually means the Java Runtime Environment (JRE.)

Comment: What's the error you get when trying to run the .jar in the computer where it doesn't work? To get an error message, try running it from the console: java -jar jar-file

Comment: I think your "external libraries" are not in the class path when launching at your work pc.

Comment: Well, I want to fix this problem where only the interface works and no option within that interface is working.

Comment: Does the class path have to be the same for both of my pc's to work?

Comment: java -Xmx1024m -jar filename.jar works, program works fine!!! what now? edit: it gives me heap space error if I do java -jar filename.jar Exact erorr: "Exception in thread "AWT-EVENTQUEUE-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Comment: File - Export - Runnable JAR File - Package required libaries into generated JAR